# How to pass environment variable in docker compose up command?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to pass an environment variable in `docker compose up` command, but as far as I see it is only possible with `docker compose run` command as mentioned official documentation:

> Set environment variables with docker compose run --env

> Similar to docker run --env, you can set environment variables in a one-off container with docker compose run --env or its short form docker compose run -e:

```
docker compose run -e DEBUG=1 web python console.py
```

I a trying to integrate Spring Cloud Vault to a Spring Boot app and need to keep the token of the vault secure without using k8, etc. For this purpose, when I run the application, I can pass the environment variable (vault_token variable), but I also need to pass these variable when I run docker compose as shown below:

```
docker compose up -e vault_token=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 --build
```

So, how can I do this? Note that I do not want to read from `.env` file and just pass while running the command for security reason.

***docker-compose.yml:***

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  vault:
    container_name: vault
    image: vault
    restart: always
    environment:
      VAULT_DEV_LISTEN_ADDRESS: '0.0.0.0:8200'
#      VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
      VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID: ${vault_token}
    ports:
      - '8200:8200'
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/logs:/vault/logs
      - ./volumes/file:/vault/file
      - ./volumes/config:/vault/config
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
```

**Note:** I use **Windows 11**

Comment: Please show an example `docker-compose.yml` file that you use with this command along with a `Dockerfile` if it makes sense. Note this doesn't have to be your entire `docker-compose.yml`, it only needs to show where the environment variables are used.

Comment: Yes, you are right and I was thinking of that. I added, could you pls have a look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> just pass while running the command for security reason

This puts your token in your shell history, which should not be considered secure... Thus, why `.env` file would be preferred.

But you could also use interpolation instead.

```yaml
env:
  - MY_VARIABLE
```

or

```yaml
env:
  MY_VARIABLE: ${MY_VARIABLE}
```

With

```
MY_VARIABLE=foobar docker compose up
```

or (assuming linux)

```
export MY_VARIABLE=foobar
docker compose up
```

Note that these also expose your token as plaintext in your terminal history, however. To work around this, you could `source` an external file, or wrap `docker compose up` in a script.

---

If you were to use Kubernetes, however (or even, Nomad), then Vault secrets can be mounted as direct environment variables to containers, and therefore your code does not need to use Vault API directly, at all, therefore does not require a token.

Comment: Hmmm, good point that I did not think (terminal history). I agree that k8 is the best way, but for now (as beginner) I want to stick a solution without k8. So, may I get your valuable opinions about these points? -->>>

Comment: Normally I pass the environment variables via `.env` file to my `docker-compose.yml` and `application.yml` files by interpolation and when publishing or sending the project to the users / customers, I just add demo values as environment variables in this file. Then warn the users / customers to update all the parameters in this `.env` file. However, in this scenario, I am not sure if the users will need one of these parameters (vault token) after running docker-compose. Suppose that I send the project to the customer, they updated the values in the .env file. Then run docker compose. -->

Comment: Then they delete the content of this `.env` file. In this case, they will need most of these parameters e.g. (vault_token, database_password) again whenever they run the app. Is that true? If so, they will need to keep these sensitive data in that file, right?

Comment: @jonathan A `.env`  file should not be included in the project, such as a Git repo. It should be added to a `.gitignore`. You can add `.env.example` with blank values. Then you should document how to use it, and trust that users will read it. There is no workaround, and they should expect an error if a variable is not defined

Comment: Alternatively, you can document using minikube and Helm with Vault Operator deployed... Anyone running Docker for Desktop nowadays already has an available Kubernetes cluster than can be used, and there is no specific need for Docker Compose for complicated workflows that don't actually require the Vault SDK in the source code.

Comment: Ok, normally I add `.env` to `.gitignore` but in this kind of situations, user will need to use it. So, I will provide an `.env` file with blank value, but should it be `.env.example` ? I mean, why not `.env` instead of it?

Comment: I will also document, but as far as I see, I think you suggest to use Kubernetes in order to get rid of this kind of issues (securing token also for vault). I will of course, but for this specific example is just a beginner and would not want to use it.

Comment: 1) Don't share `.env` because that's your own file with your own secrets. Therefore you shouldn't commit that file. For example, running a new Vault container creates a completely different token 2) A "beginner" with no knowledge in anything doesn't know the difference between Docker Compose or Minikube. As mentioned, if Docker Desktop is being used, kubernetes is already available, and Vault Operator can be installed in it. I've come across multiple open source projects in the last few months that have no compose file, but do have Helm Charts

Answer (score 1):

The **var** in the "**environment**" session, will be used inside of container. If u need set a variable inside container, its fine.

To use variables of system while docker compose deploy the container, just only call it:

Define your environment variable **vault_token** in the system(Linux):

```
export vault_token="Token12345"
```

Get the variable in the docker compose file, for example in the **command** session:

```
command: server -dev -dev-root-token-id=${vault_token}
```